# Any way to find out my Amazon Product API Limits

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was given an Amazon awsAccessKeyId and awsSecretKey,

also our company has affiliated with Amazon, we get a Associate Tag​.

And I was told we may get higher API limits, because we are affiliated.

But I don't have any detailed info about the API limits,

I want to know how many calls i can make in a second

Is there any way I could check our API Key status?

The call i use will be check product info like:

```
Service=AWSECommerceService
&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=[ID]
&IdType=ASIN
.....
```

Comment: It's related to the api, and it's useful information...

Answer (score 3):

When you exceed the requests limit, Amazon Product Advertising API sends a (possibly gzipped) response with 503 status code. Example response for `ItemLookup` query:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-08-01/">
    <Error>
        <Code>RequestThrottled</Code>
        <Message>AWS Access Key ID: YOUR-AWS-ACCESS-KEY-ID. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>fabebd87-54a2-44ec-b547-deb5feee900a</RequestId>
</ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 2):

The rules have changed since @at0mzk's answer.

You have to make sales to use the API. The limits are set by sales in the last 30 days.

> Effective 23-Jan-2019, the usage limit for each account is calculated based on revenue performance attributed to calls (also called requests) to the Product Advertising API (PA API) during your account’s latest 30-day trailing period.
>
> Each account used for Product Advertising API is allowed an initial usage limit up to a maximum of 1 request per second and a cumulative daily maximum of 8640 requests per day (TPD) for the first 30-day period after your account has been approved. Following that period, your PA API usage limit will solely be based on your shipped item revenue. Your account will earn a usage limit of 1 TPD for every 5 cents or 1 TPS (up to a maximum of 10 TPS) for every $4320 of shipped item revenue generated via the use of Product Advertising API for shipments in the previous 30-day period.

[Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/TroubleshootingApplications.html)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's not way of checking exactly what those limits are and they will change based on the performance of your account.

It seems that the minimum rate limits are:

- 1 request per second
- 8640 requests per day

Those limits will increase if your account has a good performance (as in shipped items revenue) using the API links.

---

**From:** [Amazon Product API - Troubleshooting](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/troubleshooting/api-rates.html)

> **API Rates**
>
> Curious to know how we provision API call rates for Product Advertising API 5.0? First, some definitions:
>
> - **TPS** – Transactions per second, refers to the maximum number of API calls you can make in one second. Each API call counts as one transaction. For example, if you send 10 ASINs in the request parameter of a GetItems() call, it counts as a single transaction.
> - **TPD** – Transactions per day, refers to the maximum number of API calls you can make in one day. If Associate has 1 TPS and 8640 TPD, then maximum of 1 request can be sent per second and 8640 per day. Even if 1 TPS is there, once TPD is exhausted requests will be throttled.
> - **Primary Account** – This refers to the Amazon username (email address) and password that you used to create your Associates account and used to generate Product Advertising API 5.0 credentials.
> - **Shipped revenue** – This refers to the total sales volume of all items Amazon has shipped from orders resulting from clicks through links you created using Product Advertising API 5.0.

**Also:**

> **As soon as you create your Product Advertising API 5.0 credentials**, you are allowed an initial usage limit up to a **maximum of one request per second** (one TPS) and a cumulative **daily maximum of 8640 requests** per day (8640 TPD) for the first 30-day period. This will help you begin your integration with the API, test it out, and start building links and referring products to your readers.
>
> Your PA API usage limit will be **adjusted based on your shipped item revenue**. Your account will earn a usage limit of **one TPD for every five cents or one TPS (up to a maximum of ten TPS) for every $4320 of shipped item revenue generated via the use of Product Advertising API 5.0** for shipments in the previous 30-day period. For correct attribution of shipped item revenue please ensure that you always call Product Advertising API 5.0 with the primary account credentials **and retain all the URL parameters that the API returns in its response.**
>
> ...
>
> If you are trying to submit requests that **exceed your account’s usage limit, or if your access has been revoked you will receive a `429 TooManyRequests` error message from Product Advertising API 5.0.** Please refer our API integration best practices to learn more on how to avoid these situations and optimally access the API.